# return of positive array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created this code to find the arrays that have all their positive integers, but I don't understand why it only returns the first one it finds, and it does not accumulate the arrays in the general array.

```
const input = [[1, 10, -100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]];

function positiveRowsOnly(array) {
  
 let num = 0;
  
  return array.filter(el=>{
    
   for(let i=0;i<=el.length;i++){
     
     if(el[i]>0){
       num++;
     }    
   }
    
   if(el.length==num){
     return el;
   }
   
   num = 0; 

  })
}
console.log(positiveRowsOnly(input));
```

The filter method creates a new array with the elements that have met the condition, as I have in this other simple code, which returns all the even numbers, it accumulates the result of the return within the array.

```
const input = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35];

function onlyEven(array) {
  
  return array.filter(num =>{
    if(num%2==0){
      return num;
    }
  })
}

onlyEven(input);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually simplify your code - just combine `.filter` with `.every` on the nested arrays to filter out those arrays containing negative numbers:

```js
const input = [[1, 10, -100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]];

function positiveRowsOnly(array) {
  
  return array.filter(subArr =>{    
    return subArr.every(el => el > 0);
  });
}
console.log(positiveRowsOnly(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `num=0` inside the filter.
Here is the working code.

```js
const input = [[1, 10, -100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]];

function positiveRowsOnly(array) {
  
  return array.filter(el=>{
   let num = 0;
   for(let i=0;i<=el.length;i++){
     
     if(el[i]>0){
       num++;
     }    
   }
    
   if(el.length==num){
     return el;
   }

  })
}
console.log(positiveRowsOnly(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you declared `num` outside your `filter` function, so it gets incremented everytime, and this condition:

```
if(el.length==num){
  return el;
}
```

Never works. To fix it, just move the `let num = 0` declaretion inside the `filter` function, like this:

```js
const input = [[1, 10, -100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]];
    
function positiveRowsOnly(array) {  
  return array.filter(el=>{
    let num = 0;
        
    for(let i=0;i<=el.length;i++){
         
       if(el[i]>0){
           num++;
         }    
       }
        
       if(el.length==num){
         return el;
       }
       
       num = 0; 
    
   })
 }
 console.log(positiveRowsOnly(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is where you set num=0.

when you return, you don't set num=0.

try to set num=0 before you returnas:

```
const input = [[1, 10, -100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]];

function positiveRowsOnly(array) {
  
 let num = 0;
  
  return array.filter(el=>{
    
   for(let i=0;i<=el.length;i++){
     
     if(el[i]>0){
       num++;
     }    
   }
    
   if(el.length==num){
     num = 0; // here!
     return el;
   }
   
   num = 0; 

  })
}
console.log(positiveRowsOnly(input));
```